# Sending matrices to a Tensorflow-Serving module

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to send 3 dense matrices to a tensorflow-serving module. This module should take in 3 dense matrices and return a list of floats. I'm doing this in Python.

I am having serious difficulty figuring out how to do this. I'm not sure how to send more than one piece of data at a time.

I looked at this link and it looked like it would be helpful?

https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/signature_defs

But I'm not sure.

I was previously looking at this website as a resource: https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-tensorflow-models-9813b5a705d5

However,

> req_data = [{'in_tensor_name': 'inputs', 'in_tensor_dtype': 'DT_FLOAT', 'data': np.random.rand(1,2)}]
>
> prediction = client.predict(req_data, request_timeout=10)

does not seem analogous to what I'm trying to do.

Sorry if this question is pretty vague, but I have really no idea where to start. I have these 3 matrices, and apparently the model I'm sending these matrices to receives 3 matrices and outputs one list of numbers. How do I send and receive the data from this model?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this completely answers your question, but supposed that you have a `request_dict` dictionary that maps the names of the input tensors that your model expects to the matrices as `numpy` arrays, you can populate a request as follows:

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow.contrib.util import make_tensor_proto    

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'tf_serving'
request.model_spec.signature_name = 
tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY 

for k, v in request_dict.items():
    request.inputs[k].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto(v, shape=v.shape))
```

Which you can then feed to the prediction service stub as in your example.